I cant send data from form
i have a problem with sending data to my mail from form.I have a 2 form in my code, one is for "fizickaLica" one is for "pravnaLica". Now i have js code which send data from first form to my mail, but when I want to send data from second form i got my alert that said: "Došlo je do greške prilikom slanja podataka. Molimo pokušajte ponovo."("An error occurred while sending data. Please try again.") What should i do? This is my form
<div id="fizickaLica" class="tab1 active">
    <form class="form" id="checkoutForm">
        <div class="group">
            <label for="name">Ime</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Unesite ime i prezime')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="phone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="address">Adresa</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="country">Zemlja</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="country" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="city">Grad</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ldkjf8pAAAAAJ77ZZn3qOnfd17dU0kjN0847L1m"></div>
        <button class="buttonCheckout submit" id="checkoutButton" type="submit" action="index.html">Poruči</button><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="list" id="list">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice">
    </form>
</div>

<div id="pravnaLica" class="tab1">
    <form class="form" id="checkoutFormPravna">
        <div class="group">
            <label for="companyName">Naziv firme</label>
            <input type="text" name="companyName" id="companyName" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="contactName">Kontakt osoba</label>
            <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="phone">Telefon</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone1" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="address">Adresa</label>
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address1" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="country">Zemlja</label>
            <input type="text" name="country" id="country1" required>
        </div>

        <div class="group">
            <label for="city">Grad</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city1" required>
        </div><br>
        <div class="group">
            <input type="checkbox" id="privacyCheck" required>
            <label for="privacyCheck">Slažem se sa <a href="pravila-privatnosti.html">pravilom privatnosti</a></label><br>
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ldkjf8pAAAAAJ77ZZn3qOnfd17dU0kjN0847L1m"></div>
        <button class="buttonCheckout submit" id="checkoutButton1" type="submit" action="index.html">Poruči</button><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="list" id="list1">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice1">
    </form>
</div>

and I have cuple of js files but for this problem just 2 was importanr my server.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config(); // Učitaj .env datoteku

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve static files from the root directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));

// Serve the 'checkout.html' file as the default page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'checkout.html'));
});

// Endpoint to handle form submission
app.post('/send-email', (req, res) => {
    const { name, phone, address, country, city, companyName, contactName, list, totalPrice } = req.body;

    const currentDateTime = new Date().toLocaleString();

    // Extract product names and quantities from the list
    const productList = JSON.parse(list).map(item => `${item.name} (Kolicina: ${item.quantity})`).join('\n');

    // Create a transporter
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail', // Use your email provider
        auth: {
            user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // Your email address from .env
            pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS // Your email password from .env
        }
    });

    // Email options
    const mailOptions = {
        from: 'Sajt',
        to: 'pespirot@gmail.com', // Change this to your recipient email address
        subject: 'New Order',
        text: `Name: ${name || companyName}\nPhone: ${phone}\nAddress: ${address}\nCountry: ${country}\nCity: ${city}\nContact Name: ${contactName || ''}\nDate and Time: ${currentDateTime}\n\nOrder Details:\n${productList}\n\nTotal Price: ${totalPrice}`
    };

    // Send email
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.status(500).send('Error sending email');
        } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
            res.status(200).send('success');
        }
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
});

and my checkout1.js file
document.querySelectorAll('.form').forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Prvo proveri da li je reCAPTCHA potvrđena
        let captchaResponse = form.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value;

        if (!captchaResponse) {
            alert('Molimo vas da potvrdite da niste robot.');
            return;
        }

        // Prikupi podatke iz forme
        let formData = {};
        new FormData(form).forEach((value, key) => {
            formData[key] = value;
        });
        formData['g-recaptcha-response'] = captchaResponse;

        // Podesi list i totalPrice u zavisnosti od forme
        let listName = form.querySelector('input[name="list"]');
        let totalPriceName = form.querySelector('input[name="totalPrice"]');

        if (listName && totalPriceName) {
            let listCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listCart')) || [];
            let totalPrice = calculateTotalPrice(listCart);

            listName.value = JSON.stringify(listCart);
            totalPriceName.value = totalPrice;
        }

        // Kreiraj AJAX zahtev
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/send-email');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    // Resetuj korpu i preusmeri na index.html
                    resetCart();
                    window.location.href = '/index.html';
                } else {
                    alert('Došlo je do greške prilikom slanja podataka. Molimo pokušajte ponovo.');
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
});

// Funkcija za izračunavanje ukupne cene (primer, implementirajte prema vašim potrebama)
function calculateTotalPrice(listCart) {
    return listCart.reduce((total, item) => total + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
}

// Funkcija za resetovanje korpe
function resetCart() {
    localStorage.removeItem('listCart'); // Uklanja podatke iz localStorage
    listCart = []; // Prazni niz listCart

    // Ažurira HTML da odražava praznu korpu
    addCartToHTML();
}

I try to add a
<input type="hidden" name="list" id="list1">
<input type="hidden" name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice1">

to my button but all i got is error that coudnt send data at all. Now i can send data with this js but problem is that i need to confirm alert and submit again button. Any suggestions?

If you look at the request in the Network tab of DevTools, do you see the parameters being sent correctly?

No, I have  500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ checkout1.js:47 but when i submit it again after confirm the alert, its send data to mail correctly.

If you get a 500 error, you need to check the log on the server for the reason.

Any specific advice?

Not without knowing the error that's happening on the server.
